# why my node app don't start on amazon linux 2 AMI on ec2 instance and showing this error?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, node-gyp

I have transferred all my files correctly to my ec2 instance and all the node modules are downloaded successfully with package.json file , the OS of my ec2 instance is Amazon linux 2, but whenever i run npm start on the terminal i get the following error. I have searched this alot and followed many similar or same issues on the web , but still can't figure it out.

the terminal says:-

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-7-38 backbenchers]$ npm start

> learners-backend@1.0.0 start
> nodemon app.js

[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
the-backbenchers.herokuapp.com
 undefined
 0.0.0.0
/home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:135
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → /home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/build/deasync.node
 → /home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/build/Debug/deasync.node
 → /home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/build/Release/deasync.node
 → /home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/out/Debug/deasync.node
 → /home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/Debug/deasync.node
 → /home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/out/Release/deasync.node
 → /home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/Release/deasync.node
 → /home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/build/default/deasync.node
 → /home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/compiled/15.3.0/linux/x64/de                                                                                                             async.node
 → /home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/addon-build/release/install-                                                                                                             root/deasync.node
 → /home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/addon-build/debug/install-ro                                                                                                             ot/deasync.node
 → /home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/addon-build/default/install-                                                                                                             root/deasync.node
 → /home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/lib/binding/node-v88-linux-x                                                                                                             64/deasync.node
    at bindings (/home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:1                                                                                                             26:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/inde                                                                                                             x.js:30:31)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1102:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:807:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:991:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/locus/src/lo                                                                                                             cus.js:6:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1102:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:807:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:991:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/backbenchers/routes/posts.js:14:13) {
  tries: [
    '/home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/build/deasync.node',
    '/home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/build/Debug/deasync.node',
    '/home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/build/Release/deasync.node                                                                                                             ',
    '/home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/out/Debug/deasync.node',
    '/home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/Debug/deasync.node',
    '/home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/out/Release/deasync.node',
    '/home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/Release/deasync.node',
    '/home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/build/default/deasync.node                                                                                                             ',
    '/home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/compiled/15.3.0/linux/x64/                                                                                                             deasync.node',
    '/home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/addon-build/release/instal                                                                                                             l-root/deasync.node',
    '/home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/addon-build/debug/install-                                                                                                             root/deasync.node',
    '/home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/addon-build/default/instal                                                                                                             l-root/deasync.node',
    '/home/ec2-user/backbenchers/node_modules/deasync/lib/binding/node-v88-linux                                                                                                             -x64/deasync.node'
  ]
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

node version is v15.3.0

npm version is v7.0.14

nvm version is 0.34.0

Kindly help me with this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downgraded the node version to 12.0.0 . Now it is working fine

Comment: That's not a solution, just a workaround unfortunately :(