# Installing Jest in Vue 3 gives error "Cannot locate the bindings file" for deasync on Linux

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, node-deasync

I want to use the Vue unit test utilities for Jest. This works fine on Windows, but I got an error on Linux.

This is what I did:

```
vue create my-project
```

- Select `Manually select features`
- Select `Choose vue version`
- Deselect `Babel`
- Select `Typescript`
- Select `Linter / Formatter`
- Select `Unit Testing`
- Enter
- Select `3.x (preview)`
- Answer 'y' to `Class-style component syntax`
- Answer 'n' to `Use Babel alongside ...`
- `Pick a linter`: Select `ESLint + standard config`
- `Pick additional lint features`: Select `Lint on save`
- `Pick a unit testing solution`: Select `jest`
- `Where do you prefer placing config`: Select `In package.json`
- Answer 'n' to `Save this as a preset for future projects?`

Then it attempts to create the project with the following output:

```
Vue CLI v4.5.10
✨  Creating project in /home/admiraal/my-project.
  Initializing git repository...
⚙️  Installing CLI plugins. This might take a while...

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/admiraal/my-project/node_modules/deasync
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node ./build.js
npm ERR! `linux-x64-node-15` exists; testing
npm ERR! Problem with the binary; manual build incoming
npm ERR! stdout=
npm ERR! err=Error: Command failed: /home/admiraal/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.1/bin/node quick-test.js
npm ERR! /home/admiraal/my-project/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:135
npm ERR!   throw err;
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
npm ERR!  → /home/admiraal/my-project/node_modules/deasync/build/deasync.node
npm ERR!  → /home/admiraal/my-project/node_modules/deasync/build/Debug/deasync.node
...
(many "npm ERR!" lines follow)
```

The same error appears when I try to add Jest to an existing successfully created project using

```
vue add unit-jest
```

Deinstalling and re-installing deasync does not solve the problem.

Comment: Probably don't use Node 15 at all, stick to LTS.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to downgrade node to version 12.0.0.

[This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65137792/why-my-node-app-dont-start-on-amazon-linux-2-ami-on-ec2-instance-and-showing-th) helped me to find this solution.

To downgrade, perform the following steps:

```
nvm install 12.0.0
nvm alias default 12.0.0
nvm use default
```